aws api getting cors isssue while accessing it in html
i am getting cors issue in angularjs17 for simple fetching the apis from the aws
all the cors in aws is properly set
getting issue
ccess to fetch at 'https://fg5fxm5fo.execute-api.ap-south-9.amazonaws.com/rest_Api/fetch_details' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Access to fetch at 'https://fg5fxm5fo.execute-api.ap-south-9.amazonaws.com/rest_Api/fetch_details' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
